# How to predict string in ML.Net

Tags: c#, ml.net

I need to develop an ML.Net Application to predict the subject from a statement. For instance I have the following sentences.

1. The color of the shirt is red
2. She is a beautiful cat.
3. That car can travel very fast.
4. Roses are red.
5. It is raining heavily.

From the above sentences i need to have the following predictions.

1. Shirt
2. Cat
3. Car
4. Roses
5. Raining.

I am very new to ML.Net and hence I don't have an idea on which algorithm to use or how to go about it. If Anyone can put some light to this, it will be grateful..

Thank you in advance

I have very limited experience on ML.Net or ML in general. I have tried a few examples based on sentiment analysis.

Answer (score 3):

ML.NET's algorithms cover the most classical machine learning problems: classification, regression, clustering.

The problem you describe is mostly resembling [Sequence labeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_labeling), or 'POS tagging' (POS stands for 'part of speech'). These days, these problems are often solved with various flavors of recurrent neural networks, which ML.NET doesn't support yet.